# Copy file from ZFS to ext4

Tags: zfs

I have some files in a ZFS pool.

```
zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
ZFS   7.27T  4.03G  7.26T        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -


zfs list
NAME                USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
ZFS                66.0G  7.08T       96K  /ZFS
ZFS/file1          66.0G  7.14T     1.62G  -
ZFS/file2          66.0G  7.14T       22K  -
```

But /ZFS dir (mountpoint) is empty.

```
ls -la /ZFS
total 5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    2 Oct  8 12:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Oct 13 12:40 ..
```

I want to copy these files to another disk (sdc1 on the same computer) with ext4.

How to do that?

Comment: Are the dataset / filesystem ZFS mounted ? Check with `df`. Depending on if it is a ZFS mountpoint or a legacy one, you should be able to mount it with `zfs mount .a` (will mount all defined zfs datasets) or `mount -F zfs ZFS` (and maybe `mount -F zfs ZFS/file1` and `mount -F zfs ZFS/file2`) ... see  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5461/gaynd.html for more info.

Comment: Yes ZFS is mounted. df lists it wirh mountpoint /ZFS and zfs mount does the same.

Answer (score 0):

file1 and file2 are ZVOL's. These are virtual disks. They can be mounted like real disk'.

They exist as dev in /dev/zvol/ZFS/

```
fdisk -l /dev/zvol/ZFS/file1
Disk /dev/zvol/ZFS/file1: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 8192 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 8192 bytes / 8192 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4258469C-739C-4D09-1784-A64B43E67596
```

One can mount them.

```
mount /dev/zvol/ZFS/file1 /mnt
```